# Como converter de Texto para Número via código para EXCEL em C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Tenho um programa que lê dados de um arquivo de texto e o exporta para um relatório excel.

Estou com um problema na transcrição dos números, no arquivo txt tenho dados nesse formato:

```
8,000000
```

esse valor deve ser encarado como 8 (número) pelo relatório, logo fiz uma rotina para remover esse ",000000" e funciona, eis o código

```
//trim porquê o número vem com alguns espaços 
string content = itensCarac[indexColumnText].Replace(",000000", "").Trim();
planConfig.Cells[indexLine, indexColumn++] = content;
```

Acontece que existem números no relatório nesse formato:

```
4.700,000000
```

Em teoria a mesma lógica funcionaria. mas o Excel encara esse número como "4,7"(Sabe deus porquê), ele "transformou" o ponto em uma virgula e matou os 00.

Se eu não aplico essa lógica nas linhas onde tem ponto flutuante, o excel trata elas como texto, e a conversão do excel para número resolve o problema. Como mostra a imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis a pergunta:

Como fazer essa conversão de texto para número via código da maneira correta?

OBS:

já tentei usar o

```
NumberFormat = "0.0";
```

ou o

```
NumberFormat = "0";
```

e os resultados foram "4,7"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Double.Parse` com `CultureInfo("pt-br")`, caso sempre tenha números nessa coluna.
Ou `Double.TryParse` caso não tenha certeza se sempre virá um número nessa coluna.

No seu caso seu código pode ficar assim, nem precisa de trim ou replace :

```
string content = Double.Parse(itensCarac[indexColumnText], cultura);
planConfig.Cells[indexLine, indexColumn++] = content;
```

Abaixo fiz um código com o primeiro exemplo "8,000000" e com "4.700,000000". Também adicionei um outro caso "4.700,100000" e mais dois exemplos usando TryParse ao invés do Parse.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;//Para o CultureInfo

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {           
        //Setei a cultura para Português Brasil.
        CultureInfo cultura = new CultureInfo("pt-br"); 

        //Teste com 8,000000
        double valor8 = Double.Parse("8,000000", cultura);
        Console.WriteLine(valor8);

        //Teste com 4.700,000000
        double valor4_7 = Double.Parse("4.700,000000", cultura);        
        Console.WriteLine(valor4_7);

        //Teste com 4.700,100000
        double valor4_7_1 = Double.Parse("4.700,100000", cultura);
        Console.WriteLine(valor4_7_1);

        //Teste com TryParse 1.230,15
        double x=0;     
        bool testeEhNumerico = Double.TryParse("1.230,15",NumberStyles.Any,cultura, out x);                     
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(testeEhNumerico);

        //Teste com TryParse caso não venha um número 
        double y=0;     
        bool testeNaoNumerico = Double.TryParse("Não sou numérico!",NumberStyles.Any,cultura, out y);   
        Console.WriteLine(y);
        Console.WriteLine(testeNaoNumerico);

    }
}
```

Os resultados são :

```
8
4700
4700.1
1230.15
True
0
False
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando com comentários em
https://dotnetfiddle.net/f0u3io

Tentei um código bem lúdico, espero que esteja claro.

Comment: Funcionou!!!! os resultados foram exatamente os esperados com essa implementação. Muito obrigado !!!

Answer (score 2):

Não sei muito bem se vai te ajudar, mas tem algo no stackoverflow em inglês: [How can I convert String to Int?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019804/6416619)

*Traduindo é algo +- assim:*

Ele manda você tentar isto:

```cs
int x = Int32.Parse(variável);
```

ou, de uma forma melhor: *(Que creio eu que de acordo com seu objetivo não seria interessante mas é bom conhecer)*

```cs
int x = 0;
Int32.TryParse(variável, out x);
```

Onde `Int32.TryParse` retorna um `bool` que pode ser usado em um if

returns a bool you can its return value to make decisions about the results of the parsing attempt:

int x = 0;

if (Int32.TryParse(TextBoxD1.Text, out x))
{
    // you know that the parsing attempt
    // was successful
}

> The TryParse method is like the Parse method, except the TryParse
>   method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails. It
>   eliminates the need to use exception handling to test for a
>   FormatException in the event that is invalid and cannot be
>   successfully parsed. - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

Traduzindo.
 O metodo TryParse é parecido com o Parse, exceto que o TryParse não da throw em nenhuma exception quando a conversão falha. Isso elimina a necessidade de controlar exceções e tentar desvendar através dos formatos dessas exceções quando a ação for falha.

**Lembre-se que também tem o** `Convert.ToInt`

```cs
Convert.ToInt16(variável);
Convert.ToInt32(variável);
Convert.ToInt64(variável);
```

Link do site da Microsoft em [Inglês](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679(v=vs.110).aspx) que informa sobre o `Convert` e em [Português](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397679.aspx)

Comment: ótimo! implementei no código e agora sei onde está cada valor e seu determinado tipo. Muito obrigado, agora só falta a exibição.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve estar **usando o Excel em Português**, mas os dados são tratados **originalmente em Inglês**, assim, **4.700,000000** é para o Excel (da forma que está enviando os dados) igual a **4.7**, pois em Inglês o simbolo para separação de milhar é a **vírgula** (desconsiderada neste caso porque vem depois do ponto), e o **ponto** é o separador das casas decimais.

A sugestão é você **substituir os caracteres vírgula no lugar de ponto e visse-versa antes de enviar para o Excel**, passando a enviar o número do exemplo desta forma:

**4,700.000000** (forma em Inglês)

**Fazendo isso vai funcionar!**

Se enviar como texto, envie assim "**=4,700.000000**", que o Excel tratará como valor **se a célula estiver formatada para valor**, e passará automaticamente para a notação em **Português**.

Comment: Então Leo, a ideia é boa, mas se outra pessoa abrir esse relatório e não tiver essas configurações, o valor sera 4,7 ???

Comment: Neste caso você vai precisar de dois arquivos, como se fossem para dois banco de dados diferentes, passando os dois arquivos; eu mudaria a extensão do que eu vou usar para o cliente não saber de cara que é um "txt", o outro normal. Outra solução seria criar uma macro para ler este arquivo, jogar estes valores em campo texto, pela própria macro, trocar as vírgulas por ponto e o ponto por vírgula (você vai precisar de um terceiro caractere para fazer isso), e ao tratar os valores, copiar para a folha definitiva com os campos em formato de valor já tratados para a notação em Português. É isso.

Comment: Detalhe, o que te passei não é "dica", é o problema real pelo Excel trabalhar em Inglês, apesar de apresentar funções e dados em linguas nativas. Eu tive o problema e por isso sei disso.